# css how make text so that the it starts from the same "column" (picture explained)

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I need some help with aligning the text. I want to achieve this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aKvl.jpg (taken from facebook). As you see, the text doesn't go under the picture, its always to the right of it. But when I try to implement the same, the line that passes the picture, goes under the picture. Here is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/DmXkq/

btw I am using html5/css3.

Thanks,
Gasim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to:

```
.description
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DmXkq/1/

Comment: @Gasim You're welcome ;) You might want to tick that little checkmark to accept this answer if it helped you ;)